# Weird triangles when uniting

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to make a lattice pattern of sorts, but I'm getting a weird result...
Here are my steps:

I start with a rectangle.
[image]

And use Effect > Distort & Transform > Transform...
[image]

And I expand the appearance...
[image]

Unite the paths...
[image]

And end up with these weird gray triangles...
[image]

What's causing these triangles and how can I avoid them?

Comment: Is it a real triangles, can you select them?  Can you find them in Layer Panel?

Comment: Ha! thanks, I just realized I could delete them from the layer panel.

Comment: OK, but the reason for their appearance is still unclear.

Comment: Yeah it was like the "left overs".. try it yourself and you'll see..

Comment: Try using CPU preview

Comment: Turning off GPU rendering fixes the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Yes those are left overs / stray points. You can delete it manually and automatically. 
Manually group them all in one group then separate the main path (lines you want to retain) then put it in another layer; then delete the unwanted group. 
Automatically delete it by clicking Object>Path>Clean Up
[image]

Then make sure to check some option then click OK
[image]